# Windows service application self-defense in Delphi ( rad studio )

Tags: delphi, service

I am building a Windows service app using Delphi , RAD Studio 10

Upon my investigation I came across with a Eset Windows service which wonderfully was protecting itself from being Stopped or terminated.

On stopping the service using (windows service manager) or (end process button)
or (end task button) following error messages occurs :

The operation couldn't be completed.

access denied.

same thing is true with its registry keys . The error message is :

Can not delete info: Error while deleting key

I tested Administrator access and system access. in both cases i was not successful.

I want to build such self-defense mechanism for my own application protecting my service and registry key.

Any idea would be helpful.

Thank you for your time.

update :

I want to know how i can do it in Delphi ... that's why it is tagged Delphi

and If someone wants to stop the service or uninstall it ....

he or she can just use my own applications UI to do it.

edit 2 :

As Remko mentioned I thnk DACL and ACL is better way to handle it , I couldn't find any good reference for it. Is there any good reference for Delphi language?

Comment: Two tricks: 1) you have to monitor changes to the relevant registry keys, and 2) You need two services guarding each other. But no system is going to be unbreakable, e.g. you need a trigger to be able to shut down the services 'regularly'. Once anyone knows the trigger, they are 'in'.

Comment: on two service protecting each other, when service1 goes down service2 brings it up and vice-versa without any error messages, but in this case access denied message that windows service manager creates is displayed. And no access is given even for editing the property of service, what ever you do to service will be denied by windows service manager itself. how do you explain this ?

Comment: How this relates to `[delphi]`? Please do not tag at random.

Comment: I am trying to Code this in Delphi and if there is any code in Delphi and any answer in Delphi i will post it here  this is the relation.

Comment: @JanDoggen you can simply set a deny ace in the service and registry acl's no need to do more difficult stuff. But the point is, this is not something you should do, the (admin) user should be able to stop a service at any time, idem for modifying registry keys

Comment: The programming language is irrelevant. This should be tagged winapi only.

Comment: how i can set deny access and gain the access again by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protecting from SCM stop is very easy. Assuming you are using `TService`, you can handle the `TService.OnStop` event and set its `Stopped` parameter to False. And assign an error code to the `TService.ErrCode` or `TService.Win32ErrCode` property.

Unless you are writing security software, you really should not protect from TaskManager termination. Admins should be allowed to kill misbehaving processes. That being said, you can use [`SetSecurityInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379588.aspx) to assign a DACL to your service process that grants/denies access to particular users and/or groups as needed.

You can also use [`ChangeServiceConfig2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988.aspx) to configure your service's "failure actions" to restart the service if it terminates unexpectedly.

To protect your Registry key, you can use the `lpSecurityAttributes` parameter of [`RegCreateKeyEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724844.aspx), or use the [`RegSetKeySecurity()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379314.aspx) function, to assign a `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` to your key that contains a DACL that grants/denies access to particular users and/or groups as needed.

Comment: I think the DACL and ACL that  Remko mentioned is better way to handle it.